# Azure REST endpoint reports internal address

Tags: wcf, rest, azure, azure-web-roles

I have made a custom REST API `http://127.0.0.1:81/Interfaces/RestApiExt.svc/Custom1/username/Admin`. Unfortunately, `System.ServiceModel.Web` operation `WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest` reports the interal endpoint address and socket, in my case `http://a2123-9023:82/Interfaces/RestApiExt.svc/Custom1/username/Admin` , this is bad as I do some OAuth authentication on the host side and thus the client and host URL must match to get matching OAuth signatures. How can I get the url that the client sent and not the internal endpoint address on the host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a work-around by using the host HTTP header which contains the "external" address and not the processing internal endpoint address. Have only tested it in my developer environment yet, but I think it would work in the Azure cloud also:

```
    public bool Authenticate(string username, IncomingWebRequestContext context)
    {
       var endPointUri = context.UriTemplateMatch.RequestUri;
       var originalUrl = endPointUri.Scheme + "://" + context.Headers["Host"] 
          + endPointUri.PathAndQuery;
       // .. OAuth specific code follows
    }
```